# regex + selecting file endings

Tags: regex

here is my [regex](https://regex101.com/r/qL9sR9/1)

I am trying to capture the files *08.tgz, *09.tgz, and *01.tgz

And this is what I have. but his also captures *10.tgz, due to the `09`

`.*\/*[09|8|1].tgz`

I know I can do `.*\/*[9|8|1].tgz` and this will only capture *08.tgz, *09.tgz, and *01.tgz, but what I want to understand is why does the 0 captre the 10.tgz file??

data

```
./backup_public_html_20160308.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160301.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160302.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160306.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160304.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160303.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160307.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160305.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160309.tgz
./backup_public_html_20160310.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

You misuse the character class as a group. Your regex `.*\/*[09|8|1].tgz` matches zero or more characters other than a newline (with `.*`) as many as possible (since `*` is a greedy quantifier), followed with zero or more `/` symbols, and then 1 symbol from the character class `[09|8|1]`  - that is, either `0`, `9`, `|`, `8`, or `1` followed with any character but a newline (since `.` matches any character but a newline) and then `tgz`.

For more details on how character classes work, see [*Character classes or Character Sets*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`. You could use this in `gr[ae]y` to match either `gray` or `grey`.
>
> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (`]`), the backslash (`\`), the caret (`^`), and the hyphen (`-`). The [usual metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use `[+*]`. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

To capture the files *08.tgz, *09.tgz, and *01.tgz, use

```
.*0[981]\.tgz
```

OR

```
^.*0[981]\.tgz$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD6oR7/1). The `^` is a start of string anchor and `$` is an end of string anchor, and thus, the `^.*0[981]\.tgz$` pattern will require a full string match.

**NOTE**: To match a literal `.` you need to ecape it or place.. yes, into a character class as `.` loses its special meaning inside it and just denotes a literal dot there.

**See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG0mB4/1)**

Comment: `^.*0[981]\.tgz$` does not work, not sure why? [regex](https://regex101.com/r/eD6oR7/2)

Comment: It depends on what string you pass, what programming language/code you are using. In the regex101 demo, you need to specify the MULTILINE flag, see [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eD6oR7/3).

Comment: BTW, my regex101 demo link at the bottom of my answer already contains `/m` modifier. Still, it is only needed for a multiline demo, in real life, I guess, you test these strings individually.

Answer (score 1):

`[09|8|1]` is character class, trying to match any of the characters included - so it will match either `0` or `9` or `8` or `1` or `|`

You might be looking for `0[189]` matching `0` followed by either `1` or `8` or `9`

Answer (score 1):

I would be explicit and use

```
.*\/*(08|09|01).tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this part of your regex where the actual matching of number is taking place.

`[09|8|1]` says

- either `0` or `9`
- either `8`
- either `1`
- either a `|`

Now you are thinking it's matching `10.tgz`. But it's actually matching `0.tgz`

And when you change it to `[9|8|1]` it says.

- either `9`
- either `8`
- either `1`
- either a `|`

Now `0.tgz` won't match.

Comment: you are doing the same mistake concerning character class as the OP does - `|` is no metacharacter inside a chracter class

Comment: @SebastianProske: I am not considering it as `alteration`. I am aware it's literal `|` inside class. Am explaining why OP mistook match of `0.tgz` for `10.tgz`.

Comment: `[9|8|1]` will match `9`,`|`,`8`,`1` - `[981]` will match `9`,`8`,`1`

Comment: @SebastianProske: Yes I know. I was only pointing out the numbers used inside class. Anyways I will make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You've confused character class and an alternation.

Try this:

```
.*0(9|8|1)\.tgz
```

Or more simply:

```
.*0[981]\.tgz
```

Note also repairs to other parts of your regex.